# Python: numerical elements in a list cant be converted into integers

Tags: python-3.x, jython-2.7

Hello people,
               I've got a problem with my code. For some reason the values are not converted to integers from strings and are not adding up. Here is my code.

```
def SumOfState(i,j):
 cf=readPopest(file1)
 sum2=[]
 sum7=[]
 Diff=0
 for  y in range((j)): 
  StateList=str(cf[y+i]).split(',')
  sum2.append(StateList[2])
  sum7.append(StateList[7])
  results2 = [int(i) for i in sum2]
  results7 = [int(i) for i in sum7]
 print sum(results2)
 print sum(results7)
```

Error message : Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

```
cf=readPopest(file1)
```

the code ^^ gives a list containing words and numbers. One element  is taken % split into sublists.

Ive tried the int() function and the for loop variant of it.

suggest me an edit, please.
Really appreciate any help.
Thanks. 
-Addie Vanhala

Comment: yes.@user3684792 " Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess looking at you code, it is because sum2 and sum7 contain non integers, probably because some part of file1 (accessed though readPopest) is non int.